# Отключение отображения шкал значений осей в OxyPlot WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Хотелось бы узнать, каким образом можно отключить шкалы (помечены в красном круге на изображении) на графике. Требуется, чтобы контур графика имел форму прямоугольника, без каких либо подписей, так как в моем случае требуется отразить в графике лишь динамику и числа совсем не важны. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимостью осей можно управлять через установку свойства `IsAxisVisible`.

Если вы настраиваете отображение графика в XAML то разметка может выглядеть так

```
<oxy:Plot Title="График без осей">
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" IsAxisVisible = "False"  />
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" IsAxisVisible = "False" />
    </oxy:Plot.Axes>
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries Title="Sin (x)"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
                        Color="Red" />
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Отображение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]